# Can't remote connect to mysql server

Tags: mysql, remote-access

i can't remote connect to mysql server  (Ubuntu Server).
I see other answers about this topic but  it isn't right for me.
I'm  trying comment bind-address = 127.0.0.1 using the # symbol
I'm  trying  bind-address = myIPserver
I'm take mysql user all privilegies for all hosts,

but when i'm trying remote connect "mysql -h ServerIP -u root -p" i see error 
"ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ServerIP' (111)"

It's strange, but i'm trying to change default mysql port (/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf) in 3307, and i don't see that this port is listened, i only see 
"tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN"

Maybe somebody had this problem?

Comment: You need to "bounce" the server when you change config. `mysqladmin -u root  -p shutdown` and then restart mysql

Second, try to use 0.0.0.0 , it's more generic and will connect to lal interfaces

Third, remote will require you to `GRANT` privileges to the external IP

Comment: Thanks, this solution helped me